# Differing RAM consumption due to variable ordering

Tags: c, embedded

Summary:
It seems the RAM consumption of c code depends on variable ordering. Is there a way to automatically optimize it?

Longer version:
Here I paste two versions of code that differ only in variable ordering.

Version 1:

```
static unsigned long b=1;
static unsigned char a=1;

unsigned long myfunc(){
  return a+b;
}
```

Version 2:

```
static unsigned char a=1;
static unsigned long b=1;

unsigned long myfunc(){
  return a+b;
}
```

Compile with DIAB compiler for PowerPC arch, using following compiler options, and check the size of ram-consumption in both object files using gnu's size utility I find a difference of 3 bytes.

```
dcc.exe  -Xsmall-data=10 -tPPCE200Z4VFF:simple -c -o version1.o version1.c
```

The RAM consumption for first case is 5 bytes whereas for second case it is 8 bytes. Should it be like this?

The difference in the generated assembly for both cases is also just the order of the variables. Is there a way to automatically optimize the variable ordering to save RAM? I guess the ordering should always be according to decreasing size of the variables.

Reference:
Diab compiler options:
http://www.embedded-tools.de/sites/default/files/pdf/wr_diab_compiler_options_reference_5.9.3-R2.pdf

Comment: This is due to alignment... This question may helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271596/question-related-to-alignment

Comment: Have you enabled optimizations? If your compiler cannot handle something as simple as global varible placement, it doesn't sound very good compiler. It's of course possible, that due to small number of variables, it simply doesn't care. You should try with big application, and with size optimizations enabled.

Comment: @user694733: Yes tried with optimizations enabled, but did not help. With big application, we optimized such cases with hand and squeezed quite some juice out of already saturated RAM. So the compiler is dumb for sure. But is there any compiler that does this for global variables? Does gcc do this? If yes, with what option?

Comment: @user6261336 Unfortunately compilers I know wouldn't help you. However, have you looked at the linker options? Manual you linked had several placement related, such as `-Xsort-section-by-alignment`.

Answer (score 2):

Your compiler is padding the `long` after `char` to preserve alignment.  You might possibly find a way to disable this, but it's not  generally a good idea.  Instead, it is up to you to pack your variables efficiently--this is something that needs to be done even in some cases on full-size computers, not just embedded.  For example:

```
struct thing
{
    char c1;
    int i1;
    char c2;
    int i2;
    char c3;
    int i3;
};
```

The above is bad, because it wastes 9 bytes on padding, bringing the total size to 24 bytes when it should be just 16.  If you create lots of such objects, you're wasting a third of your memory (RAM, but more importantly cache).

Comment: Is the compoiler not allowed to arrange variable declarations freely, or perhaps only when optimizations are flagged?

Comment: @Linuxxon The compiler is not allowed to re-arrange variables in a struct.

Comment: @Linuxxon: In limited cases maybe, but in general no, because for example in my struct above, the programmer may rely on the ordering of the fields (e.g. they may memcpy the struct to/from network messages).

Comment: @Leandros yeah, but the variables aren't in a struct in the question which was what I was thinking of. Is it still the same?

Comment: @Linuxxon: I think in some limited cases, perhaps including the case in your question using global variables, it might be possible to do reordering.  But I've never seen a compiler that did it.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: Okay, thanks for answering. I just have some memory of discussing this in a computer architecture class. It wasn't x86 so might not hold true outside that architecture.

Comment: @Linuxxon Compiler and linker can re-arrange variables if those variable belongs in different section [data or bss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment)

Comment: Theoretically could it be possible that stack variables are re-arranged (I don't know if it's legal in terms of the C standard). I've tested it real quick with GCC and clang, and neither of these re-arranges any stack allocations.

Comment: I don't see how this answers question at all. Structure fields are handled differently from global variables. Yes, it's due to alignment, but any half-good compiler could handle that for global variables.